# How to delete files from the recycle bin?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, recycle-bin

How to delete files from the recycle bin?
Any ideas?

Comment: Move to C:\RECYCLED and delete all files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

programmatically:

http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/windows/empty_recycle_bin.html

or

http://www.delphi-zone.com/2010/02/how-to-empty-recycle-bin/